# How to keep image ratios through devices?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm programming a simple cards game but my images are not the same between my emulator and my own phone.
I tried `android:src="@drawable/card_a"` and `android:background="@drawable/card_a"` but it doesn't work. Here is some screenshots to explain that:

[image]
[image]
 - With android:src it displays very small images.

I'd like to see the same display from my emulator in my phone.

Comment: post your layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LinearLayout weight like this:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weight_sum="5" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

This way you always gonna get 5 same width views with.

Answer (score 2):

The problem does not seem to be the image background, but the View containing this image. Probably you should use `android:weight="1"` in all of them, and place all these ImageViews within a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 0):

you add the `android:scaleType="FitInCenter"` in your Layout file.